# Negotiating "work for hire" rights back?

Tags: employment, work-for-hire

On this [page](http://web.law.columbia.edu/keep-your-copyrights/copyrights/works-made-hire) it says:

> "Even when you create works as part of your job, it may be possible for you to
> negotiate to obtain some rights back from your employer."

How would you go about doing that?
Are there any good examples?

If it helps I'm interested in the juristiction of the UK (England)

For some context see: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4378/help-with-getting-permission-to-open-source-a-small-piece-of-software

Comment: In the U.S. I imagine you'd tell your boss you'll only do the assignment if you get whatever rights you want. Then the boss accepts, rejects (you're fired) or counters. As always, negotiation is only advisable if you can walk away.

Comment: "Hey boss, I want to buy back my copyright in X. I think $Y is a fair price. What do you think?"